# Звідки в українській мові слово "охоронник", і в чому його відмінність від "охоронця"?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами

Донедавна я не зауважував, що багато київських супермаркетів запрошують на роботу *охоронників*. Сьогодні, з цікавості взявши до рук Книгу відгуків і пропозицій в одному з них, прочитав приблизно таке:

> Пропоную у всіх оголошеннях про роботу замінити слово-покруч
>   "**охоронник**" на український відповідник "**охоронець**".

Чи справді це слово є нетиповим для української мови? Наприклад, Словник української мови в 11 томах [знає](http://sum.in.ua/s/okhoronnyk) про *охоронника* і каже, що це слово означає

> те саме, що **охоронець**.

Answer (score 12):

До 1933 року словники [пишуть](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=rusb&dicts=all&highlight=on) «охоронник», хоча Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов) зазначає, що це росіянізм зі значенням «сотрудник охранного отделения», тобто таємної поліції, а це не зовсім те, що ми зараз цим словом називаємо. Російсько-український словник 1948 р. (М. Калинович, Л. Булаховський, М. Рильський) теж пише «охоронник».

А як ми [подивимося](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C&scope=ukrq&dicts=all&highlight=on), що ж таке «охоронець», то побачимо, що в цього слова значення зовсім инше: *рос.* «защитник», «охранитель», «телохранитель», «[aнгел-]хранитель» – [янгол]-охоронець.

Отже, виходить, що в сучасних супермаркетах працюють саме **охоронники**, а не охоронці. Суфікс *-ник* на позначення професії є звичайним українським суфіксом, згадаймо такі професії / роди занять як *лірник, пасічник, сотник, землевласник, месник, самотник, грабіжник, книжник, будівник, рятівник* тощо, подібних українських слів сотні.

Comment: Чи вірно я підсумую, що *охоронник* опікується майном, а *охоронець* — людиною?

Comment: @NashBridges - Я б сказав так: охоронник щось стереже, не дає вкрасти, а охоронець – охороняє від нападу, опікується цим, оберігає, не дає скривдити або викривити (ідею): _охоронник складу_ :: _охоронець духовности_ :: _мій охоронець (охороняє мене)_.

Comment: А хто тоді такий _сторож_?

Comment: @BohdanKuts - Сторож - це той, хто вночі охороняє об’єкт (і в якого запитують, як пройти до бібліотеки)), він теж охоронник. Сторож стоїть і охороняє щось, що його поставили охороняти, скажімо, яблуневий сад. Ви ж не хочете сказати, що в супермаркеті біля каси стоїть сторож?

Comment: @BohdanKuts - У нас у Центральній Україні в селах є такий звичай, що коли ти йдеш кудись із хати, наприклад у магазин чи далеко на город, то на вхідних дверях хати ставиться ціпок десь метр-півтори завдовжки, який спирається під кутом на двері, він зветься «сторож». Як хтось до тебе прийде, а тебе нема, то він той ціпок переставить инакше або геть прибере, аби коли ти повернешся, щоб ти знав, що до тебе хтось приходив. ))

Answer (score 1):

Зайдемо спершу на [Вікіпедію](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), одразу ж бачимо "**Не варто плутати з Охоронець (той, що захищає особу від зовнішньої агресії)**". А також:

Охоронник — це сторож: особа, що здійснює функції охорони і нагляду за об'єктом.

Слово Охоронник може означати:

> Сторож
>
> Тюремний наглядач
>
> Агент охранки (дореволюц.).
>
> Конвоїр
>
> Співробітник приватного охоронного підприємства, який здійснює функції вахтера, що перевіряє документи у співробітників і
>   відвідувачів на вході до закладу, паркувальника на автомобільній
>   стоянці підприємства, або ресторанного (клубного) швейцара, що
>   здійснює фейс-контроль.
>
> Співробітник воєнізованої охорони

А ось що про це каже [пан Авраменко](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLV5ivdPayI):

> Охоронник і охоронець - синоніми, однак є відмінності, бо  кажуть
>   "**охоронець закону**" (людина яка захищає закон), "**охоронець
>   президента**" (той, хто захищає життя), проте "**охоронник складу**".

Тому бачимо, що все таки є різниця між цими словами. А на цьому [форумі](http://forum.hrliga.com/showthread.php?t=1768) взагалі рекомендують "охоронцями" називати тих, хто охороняє людей, а "охоронниками" - територію, будівлі. Там же знайшов посилання на [Класифікатор професій](https://buhgalter.com.ua/dovidnik/klasifikator-profesiy/dodatok-b-abetkoviy-pokazhchik-profesiynih-nazv-robit/), де є і охоронник, і охоронець.

На сайті "[Як правильно](https://kak-pravilno.net/ohoronec-chi-ohoronnik-yak-pravilno/)" пишуть:

> Це слова-синоніми в значенні “той, що охороняє”. Але є деякі
>   відмінності.
>
> **Охоронець** – це той, хто охороняє закон або дбає про безпеку. Слово несе більш абстрактне значення.
>
> **Охоронник** – це той, хто охороняє певну територію. Слово використовується для позначення посади на підприємстві.

На цікаву думку наткнувся на [цьому форумі](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t2049.html):

> Обидва слова є в українській мові, проте вони не взаємозамінні. Слово
>   "охоронець" уживається частіше, бо має кілька значень: ОХОРОНЕЦЬ,
>   -нця, ч. 1. Той, хто охороняє, стереже кого-, що-небудь. 2. Той, хто піклується про збереження чого-небудь, оберігає щось. // Те, що
>   загороджує, прикриває кого-, що-небудь від чогось небажаного,
>   шкідливого, небезпечного і т. ін. 3. Той, хто захищає кого-небудь,
>   дбає про його безпеку, добробут і т. ін. 4. Той, хто стежить за
>   дотриманням чогось, піклується про непорушність, недоторканність
>   чого-небудь (звичаїв, законів і т. ін.). А слово "охоронник" є синонім
>   до слова "охоронець" лише в першому значенні, тобто охоронник -це той,
>   хто охороняє, стереже кого-, що-небудь і не більше. Тому доречно буде
>   сказати "охоронець поля" і "охоронник поля", "тюремний охоронець" і
>   "тюремний охоронник". Тут ці слова може заступити слово "сторож".
>
> Проте вислови "охоронник традицій", "охоронник архіву", "охоронник
>   закону", "охоронник моральності", "особистий охоронник" порушують
>   мовну норму. Правильно буде лише "охоронець традицій", "охоронець
>   архіву", "охоронець закону", "охоронець моральності", "особистий
>   охоронець". Тут слово "охоронець" наближається своїм значенням до слів
>   "оборонець", "захисник".

Тобто слова справді схожі, однак не завжди одне слово може замінити інше.